# swift set intersect, union, subtract

Tags: swift, set

Does anyone know how to implement set operations with user defined classes, with its property as operated conditions. For instance:

```
class myClass {
  var figure: Int!
} 

let classObj1 = myClass() 
classObj1.figure = 1

let classObj2 = myClass()
classObj2.figure = 2

let classObj3 = myClass()
classObj3.figure = 1

let set1: Set = [classObj1]
let set2: Set = [classObj2, classObj3]
```

Is there any method like: (pseudo code)

```
set2.substract(set1) {s2, s1 in s2.figure == s1.figure}
```

...so the expected result is `[classObj2]`?

Many thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Certainly. Make your MyClass conform to Hashable and Equatable in such a way that `==` compares the `figure` values. Example:

```
class MyClass : Hashable {
    var figure: Int
    init(f:Int) {figure = f}
    var hashValue : Int {return figure}
}
func ==(lhs:MyClass, rhs:MyClass) -> Bool {
    return lhs.figure == rhs.figure
}
```

Comment: Please write your own code. I answered the question you asked, namely, how to make `subtract` work the way you described for a Set of your custom class. If you don't understand my answer, don't upvote or accept it.

Comment: Done! Thanks matt.